# SwiftUI Segmented Picker Dynamic Type

Tags: swift, uikit, accessibility, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to get dynamic type to respond with a segmented picker using SwiftUI. I know I have to access the old UIKit stuff and have everything working except for it responding to dynamic type changes (colors, fonts, sizes, etc. all work).

It's very important to get this right, as our clients may have accessibility needs to enlarge the type. This is the only element in the entire app I haven't got dynamic type working on.

ALSO: I need to be able to set how large it should scale like I do when I set a Text() modifier of .dynamicTypeSize(.medium ... .xxLarge)

Everything I've read says you have to set the values on UILabel (i.e. label in my code below) but nothing is ever calling to label in the UISegmentedControl which is probably why it's not working correctly, but I haven't found one example of how to do this properly for iOS 15+.

Here's the code (it's in .onAppear): (optionsbkg, TextPrimary, and TextSecondary are custom colors I have in the assets)

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(Color("optionsbkg"))
if let fontMedium = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 14) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    label.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .footnote).scaledFont(for: fontMedium)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
        [
            .font: fontMedium,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor(Color("TextSecondary"))
        ],
        for: .normal
    )
}

if let fontBold = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    label.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .footnote).scaledFont(for: fontBold)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
        [
            .font: fontBold,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor(Color("TextPrimary"))
        ],
        for: .selected
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I truly wish Apple would figure this out already, but since we still have resort to old UIKit code to make it happen, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do it, I thought I would post the solution.

Create your segmented picker using only Text() elements, and place the UIKit code in .onAppear. You can copy/paste this exact code into a SwiftUI file in XCode and it will work. The only thing you need to remember is to change my custom colors to whatever colors you want in your project.

```
    struct TestView: View {

    @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) var sizeCategory
    @ScaledMetric var scale: CGFloat = 1

        var body: some View {

            VStack {

                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.medicationCategory.animation()) {
                    Text("Option 1")
                    Text("Option 2")
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .fixedSize()
            }
            .onAppear {
                UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(Color("optionsbkg"))
                let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .footnote)
                UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
                    [
                        .font: sizeCategory <= .xxLarge ?
                            fontMetrics.scaledFont(
                                for: UIFont(
                                    name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
                                    size: 14
                                ) ?? UIFont.systemFont(
                                    ofSize: 14
                                )
                            )
                        :
                            UIFont(
                                name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
                                size: 17
                            ) ?? UIFont.systemFont(
                                ofSize: 17
                            ),
                        .foregroundColor: UIColor(Color("TextSecondary")),
                        .kern: 0.2
                    ],
                    for: .normal
                )

                UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
                    [
                        .font: sizeCategory <= .xxLarge ?
                            fontMetrics.scaledFont(
                                for: UIFont(
                                    name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
                                    size: 14
                                ) ?? UIFont.systemFont(
                                    ofSize: 14
                                )
                            )
                        :
                            UIFont(
                                name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
                                size: 17
                            ) ?? UIFont.systemFont(
                                ofSize: 17
                            ),
                        .foregroundColor: UIColor(Color("TextPrimary")),
                        .kern: 0.2
                    ],
                    for: .selected
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This limits the dynamic text size to a max of xxL, which is what I needed. Feel free to remove the ternary if you don't wish to place a limit on large the text can scale, or change the value to the size of which you wish to place a limit.

There are a few issues to be aware of:

1. You cannot check this by using XCode's Environment Overrides to set the dynamic text size and see it change in real-time. It will change, but only if you use XCode's Environment Overrides and set the dynamic text size, go to another view, and then return to this view. You will then see the changes.
2. The type size will only change when you visit this specific page. You cannot set it globally in ContentView and expect that whenever you change the type size it will automatically update. It simply doesn't work.
3. What I ended up doing was creating a class with a static func that contained all of the UIKit code, along with a parameter of type DynamicTypeSize so that on every view a segmented picker is present, I put the @Environment variable in the struct, and call to that function in .onAppear. That at least ensures that if the user changes the type size, when they visit another view with a segmented picker, the type will reflect their choice.

If anyone has a better idea of how to accomplish this (with real-time updates???) please post a response.